# How to dump/write to a file with jsonplus?

Tags: python, json, file-io

jsonplus seems not to have a .dump(), only a .dumps() function, so how would you use jsonplus to write and read a list of namedtuples for instance?

Something to the effect of:

```
import jsonplus as json
from collections import namedtuple


Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name age')

l = [Person('bob', '28'), 
     Person('joe', '29'), 
     Person('tom', '30')]


with open('test.json', 'w') as outfile:  
    json.dump(l, outfile, indent = 4)

with open('test.json', "r") as read_file:
    read_data = json.load(read_file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write to the file the string result of `dumps`

```py
with open('test.json', 'w') as outfile:
     outfile.write(json.dumps(l))

with open('test.json', 'r') as read_file:
    read_data = json.loads(read_file.read())
```